# Sub-powerset notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have been working on a personal project showing that the power set of any finite set can be written as the union of smaller subsets that act as combinations on the parent set. This function has two values(not including the argument) that I want to display: $\mathit{s}$ that dictates the size of the subset, and $\mathit{o}$that dictates which combination of $\mathit{s}$-elements is being mentioned. I'm caught between four notations:

1. $_s\wp_{o}(S)$
2. $\wp_o^s(S)$
3. $\wp_{(s,o)}(S)$
4. $\wp(S,s)$ where the second s is the size.

with th following pros/cons:

1. Keeps all the information relatively close to the $\wp$, but is it weird to have the 'argument' s to the left?
2. It's condensed, but I hate doing superscripts for anything other than exponents( like how $f^{-1}$ doesn't mean what it looks like)
3. This one I don't have a pro for, but I don't like how it distances the set argument from the $\wp$
4. I like this one because it makes it clear that the subset size is an argument as well as the original set.

I have been leaning towards #4, but I wanted to ask for the advice of others. Thank you for you time and feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Are you simply looking for a notation for the set of $s$-element subsets of $S$? If so, there are at least two standard ones already in use: $[S]^s$, and $\binom{S}s$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Those do notate what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: I want to be able to reference the subscript o, so should I go with the 4th one as a function representing the standard notation?